# Database access strategy for a Python web app

Tags: python, psycopg2

I've been writing a Python web app (in Flask) for a while now, and I don't believe I fully grasp how database access should work across multiple request/response cycles. Prior to Python my web programming experience was in PHP (several years worth) and I'm afraid that my PHP experience is misleading some of my Python work.

In PHP, each new request creates a brand new DB connection, because nothing is shared across requests. The more requests you have, the more connections you need to support. However, in a Python web app, where there is shared state across requests, DB connections can persist.

So I need to manage those connections, and ensure that I close them. Also, I need to have some kind of connection pool, because if I have just one connection shared across all requests, then requests could block waiting on DB access, if I don't have enough connections available.

Is this a correct understanding? Or have I identified the differences well? In a Python web app, do I need to have a DB connection pool that shares its connections across many requests? And the number of connections in the pool will depend on my application's request load?

I'm using Psycopg2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked in to SQLAlchemy at all?  It takes care of a lot of the dirty details - it maintains a pool of connections, and reuses/closes them as necessary.

Comment: Yes I have. But I'm curious about how this would be done outside of SQLA.

Comment: whether or not you have a connection pool, you really do want to get yourself to a state where the database work for a request is done by the time the request finishes.  Because you don't know if the next request is EVER going to come.  The client may go away because the browser crashed, or the operator went to lunch, or the operator left on vacation!  (And if you're thinking about leaving a database transaction open between requests...please don't.)

Comment: @ChrisCurvey no, I certainly wouldn't hold open a transaction across a request. I'm more concerned with knowing how many connections I should have in the pool, and when they should be opened and when they should be closed, etc.

Comment: In that case, about the best advice I can offer is that sqlalchemy is written in Python; so, if you install it, you can dig around in the source and see what's going on under the hood.  I did a little bit of digging around, and they also seem to have done a pretty good job documenting the source.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid connection cost, seems that best way is to use pooling.
either directly with psycopg2.pool [from docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html) or via higher level abstraction layer as SQL Alchemy as underlined on comments here.